# Can anyone share the source of famous sloka gange cha yamune chaiva?

Tags: vedas, shiva, shloka

Famous sloka for water purification or during bathing:

> गङ्गे च यमुने चैव गोदावरि सरस्वति ।
>
> नर्मदे सिन्धु कावेरि जलेऽस्मिन् संनिधिं कुरु ॥

Can anyone share the source of this sloka? 

Based on my google search, it's from *ahnika sutravali verse 106*.

I am not able to find the exact text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is from [Brahmavaivarta purana](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7_(%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A1%E0%A4%83)/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%AC)

> गङ्गे च यमुने चैव गोदावरि सरस्वति ।।

> नर्मदे सिन्धु कावेरि जलेऽस्मिन्सन्निधिं कुरु ।। ६६ ।।

Comment: Thank you are the effort, What are the protocols to chant this sloka according to sasthas?

Answer (score 1):

The shlok

> गङ्गे च यमुने चैव गोदावरि सरस्वति।

> नर्मदे सिन्धुकावेरि जलेऽस्मिन्सन्निधिं कुरु

maybe found in the Naradiy Puran also.

> gaṅge ca yamune caiva godāvari sarasvati /
>
> narmade siṃdhukāveri jale 'sminsannidhiṃ kuru //
>
> **NarP_1,27.33** //

Refer the link here = http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/corpustei/transformations/html/sa_nAradapurANa.htm

Comment: Thank you are the effort, What are the protocols to chant this sloka according to sasthas?